# Python IMAP select multiple folders

Tags: python, imap

I'm trying to get the informations from all the folders but it seems that the code gives me the following error:

**command SEARCH illegal in state AUTH, only allowed in states SELECTED**

I've googled it but no results for me.

This is the code:

```
        M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('',993)
        M.login(user,password)
        folders = M.list()

        for folder in folders[1]:

            for allfolders in re.findall('"\/"(.*)',folder):

                finalfolders = allfolders.replace(" ",'')

                M.select(finalfolders, readonly=True)

                print finalfolders

                typ, data = M.search(None, 'ALL')

                for num in data[0].split():
                    typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
                    email_message = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
                    su = email_message['From']

                    allz = re.findall("<(.*)>",su)

                    for x in allz:

                        print x

                    results.write(x+'\n')
                    results.flush()
                    #print su
                M.close()
                M.logout()
```

Basically I'm trying to fetch "From", from all the folders founded into my email account.

Comment: It looks like you're ignoring the return value from `M.login`; maybe you should check it.  Which line is generating the traceback?

Comment: Hi, the problem happens after the second for loop,                 M.select(finalfolders, readonly=True) here.

If I move the rest of the code after the second loop 2 steps back unfortunately will get only the last folder but I want all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one folder selected at any given time using one IMAP connection. This means that your code should `EXAMINE` or `SELECT` a mailbox at first, then `FETCH` whatever you need to download, then do *not* call `CLOSE` because it removes messages marked for deletion, and upon entering the next loop iteration, call `EXAMINE` or `SELECT` once again, and...

Comment: Does not work. It only `EXAMINE`s the first folder & then cannot switch anymore, leading to exceptions.

Comment: what exceptions?